# Grant drop permission on stored procedure to user

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I Grant drop permission of stored procedure in SQL Server to user via script?

I tried the following, but it does not work

```
use XpressFeed_Dev
GRANT DROP ON procedure::getPartyDuns TO "INT\svc-w-corerefdata-de";

use XpressFeed_Dev
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON [getPartyDuns] TO "INT\svc-w-corerefdata-de";
```

Answer (score 0):

You must specify schema before the procedure name - like this:

```
GRANT DROP ON procedure::XpressFeed_Dev.getPartyDuns TO [INT\svc-w-corerefdata-de];
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON XpressFeed_Dev.[getPartyDuns] TO [INT\svc-w-corerefdata-de];
```

Comment: Cant make out what change you have made. Is it the quotes

Comment: I am getting an additional error Incorrect syntax near 'INT\svc-w-corerefdata-de'.

Comment: It's ok now try it

Answer (score 0):

> Permissions
>
> Requires CONTROL permission on the procedure, or ALTER permission on
>   the schema to which the procedure belongs, or membership in the
>   db_ddladmin fixed server role.

[DROP PROCEDURE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-procedure-transact-sql)

So the minimum permission of all mentioned above is `control` on a procedure because after it will be dropped the user will have no additional permissions

```
GRANT CONTROL ON object::getPartyDuns TO [INT\svc-w-corerefdata-de];
```

Comment: There is no "drop" permission, to drop an object someone has to have CONTROL permission on the procedure, or ALTER permission on the schema to which the procedure belongs, or membership in the db_ddladmin fixed server role